# Korea a lot colder than New England this year

Tags: meteorology

Normally, here in New England we consider our weather to somewhat parallel Korea's weather. However, this year it seems to be much colder in Korea. They are having record lows while we are having a relatively mild winter so far.

Why would there be such a divergence?

Comment: Over in New England your temperature is affected by the NAO and AO index(negative right now) .That could change when and if the polar vorex splits. Korea well they are having a cold surge due to high values of Siberian High.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_Seoul "The winter in Seoul is controlled by the large Siberian high pressure system (the Asiatic high), which results in predominantly cold, dry north-westerly winds. The influence of the Siberian high leads to significantly colder winter temperatures than would be expected at this latitude"

Comment: https://www.mountainwatch.com/Snow-news/2020-2021-japanese-snow-season-outlook-january-update/ "La Nina is certainly living up to all the hype, with increased convection (rainfall) over the Maritime Continent likely influencing a southward extension of the cold Siberian High into Eastern China, which in turn promotes cyclonicity (storms) about and north of Japan. Additionally, the Arctic Oscillation has been negative for over a month, further strengthening the Siberian High and allowing frigid polar air to escape and hit Japanese mountains."

Comment: And voila I have established a connection between AO and SH !